# Eliminate duplicates from UNIONS

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, union

I'm trying to create a SQL Query for a simple search bar on a social-media site. So far i have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.[user id], users.[first name] AS [Hit], users.[user profile hyperlink] AS [Hyperlink]
FROM users
WHERE users.[first name] LIKE '*web*'

UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT Users.[user id],  users.[last name], users.[user profile hyperlink]
FROM users
WHERE  users.[last name] LIKE '*web*'

UNION  
SELECT DISTINCT Users.[user id],  posts.[post content], posts.[post hyperlink]
FROM posts, users
WHERE posts.[post content] LIKE '*web*'
AND posts.[user id] = users.[user id]


UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT group.[group id], Group.[Group Name], group.[group page hyperlink]
FROM [Group]
WHERE Group.[Group Name] LIKE '*Web*'

UNION  
SELECT DISTINCT Users.[user id],  posts.[post content], posts.[post hyperlink]
FROM posts, users, posts_has_tags, tags
WHERE tags.[tag] LIKE '*web*'
AND posts_has_tags.[tag id] = tags.[tag id]
```

I dont want to add variables yet so i am fine with '*web*' being searched for. However the query returns some wrong results (i think this is to do with the last union'd query) and repeats other results for different user ids.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use of modern JOIN notation could make the source of your problem much clearer. (i.e. your last query involved 4 tables, but only "joins" two of them.)

Comment: Yea, this should be using joins, but if you are unioning them, why not just wrap the whole thing:
Select Distinct * from (Your query)

Comment: Also, `LIKE '*web*'` is the same as `= '*web*'`; `*` is not a wildcard in MySQL, `%` is.

Comment: Yes, please look at using modern ANSI JOINs instead of the older comma-syntax. You will likely get unexpected results in that last query because of those JOINs. Also, every query you have in your UNIONs should have the same columns. Can you provide some schema, example data and your expected results?

Comment: Uueerdo i am using MS Access so * is the wildcard.

Shawn: for the last part of the union i am trying to find all the posts that have the tag "web".

I need it to display the user id of ther 'post-er', the content of the post, and the hyperlink. 

The posts table has user id as a foreign key, and tags are linked to posts via post_has_tags. Does that help at all? i realise what i am doing is a bit annoying but i've got to use Access .mdb (2000) which has some frustrating drawbacks so this is where i am :(

Comment: If you are using MS Access, why do you tag your request with MySQL instead? I've removed the incorrect tag.

Comment: By the way: Unlike `UNION ALL` the operator `UNION` removes duplicates. No need for additional `DISTINCT`.

Comment: As to your problem: you got the answer in Uueerdo's first comment. In the last query you are combining all users with all posts and again with all post tags. So if only one post has a tag matching `'*web*'`, you get *all* posts combined with *all* users.

Comment: ...and (to add to what @ThorstenKettner was spelling out) all combinations of posts with users with every tag-post association (regardless of post, every post gets every post's tags).

Answer (score 0):

1st two queries can be clubbed together by combining the where clauses

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.[user id], users.[first name] AS [Hit], users.[user profile hyperlink] AS [Hyperlink]
FROM users
WHERE users.[first name] LIKE '*web*' or users.[last name] LIKE '*web*'
```

Also the 4th query returns `group.[group id]` as 1st column, others return `Users.[user id]`. Not sure how can you make distinct between two different columns, you'll get wrong data